# Sqlite not updating rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, transactions, android-sqlite

Hi I'm trying to update some rows incrementing a value in an int field but it doesn't work.
Here my snippet of code:

```
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables("TICKET");
        String[] proj = new String[]{ "TICKET","NUMERO_ARTICOLO","QUANTITA","COMMESSA_IN","CODICE_SQUADRA"};
        try{
            Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(sqlDB, proj, selection, null, null, null, null);
            sqlDB.beginTransaction();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String query =     "UPDATE MATERIALE "
                        + " SET RIMANENTE = RIMANENTE - " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("QUANTITA"))
                        + " WHERE NUMERO_ARTICOLO = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMERO_ARTICOLO"))+"'"
                        +" AND COMMESSA = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COMMESSA_IN"))+"' "
                        +" AND CODICE_SQUADRA = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CODICE_SQUADRA"))+"' ";
                Log.d("update","Query: "+query);
                sqlDB.rawQuery(query, null);
            }
            rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update("TICKET", values, selection, null);
            sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            Log.d("update","Aggiornate "+rowsUpdated+" righe");
            sqlDB.endTransaction();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
```

Last query is working

`rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update("TICKET", values, selection, null);`

but the while cycle is not working.
What I do wrong? Maybe the UPDATE `SET RIMANENTE = RIMANENTE - " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("QUANTITA"))`

I want the cycle (while) and the last update in the same transaction.

Comment: When you step through the code, is the cursor empty or does it have any rows?

Comment: You are always skipping the first row. cursor.moveToFirst() goes to the 1st row, and while (cursor.moveToNext()) will then move you to the 2nd row for the first iteration of the loop. Is that the issue here?

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst() is a typo I didn't put in the real code. The cursor is not empty I can cycle through the cursor but the rows are not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite uses file-based locking while you are inserting-updating or selecting the rows from database. This means when you are fetching the records from database using `Select` query and until the `cursor` with that `select` statement is not closed you can not `insert` `update` or `delete` in mean time.
So you should close the `cursor` and then use `execSQL` in place of `rawQuery` to fire `update`

```
    try
    {
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(sqlDB, proj, selection, null, null, null, null);
        //sqlDB.beginTransaction();
        List<String> updateSql = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                updateSql.add(    "UPDATE MATERIALE "
                        + " SET RIMANENTE = RIMANENTE - " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("QUANTITA"))
                        + " WHERE NUMERO_ARTICOLO = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NUMERO_ARTICOLO"))+"'"
                        +" AND COMMESSA = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COMMESSA_IN"))+"' "
                        +" AND CODICE_SQUADRA = '"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CODICE_SQUADRA"))+"' ");
                Log.d("update","Query: "+query);                    
            }
        } 
        finally
        {
            cursor.close();
        }
      try
      {
        sqlDB.beginTransaction();
        for (String query : updateSql)
        {
            sqlDB.execSQL(query, null); //Here it should be execSQL instead of rawQuery
        }
        rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update("TICKET", values, selection, null);

        sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        Log.d("update","Aggiornate "+rowsUpdated+" righe");
      }
      finally
      {
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT** If I read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) it is clearly mentioned that

> For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.
>   *update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])*
>   *updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)*

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the for cycle  doesn't work, no errors but the rows are not updated with the new value. The last query works as before. I tried the for cycle query in ad dump of the application db and they work on my pc.

Comment: use `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery`

Comment: I tried switching to execSQL and tables are not update and when i try to access db through the app here the result:`12-03 13:02:45.506: E/SQLiteDatabase(18803): Failed to open database '...databases/magazzino.db'.
12-03 13:02:45.506: E/SQLiteDatabase(18803): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
`

Comment: Can you paste the update queries which have been stored in `updateSql` array once you execute and the structure for data table `MATERIALE`

Comment: Ok. With execSQL(String query) is working just using the method with 1 argument cause if you use the one execSQL(String query,String[] bindgArgs) and set the second parameter to null I have an exception. Now `sqlDB.beginTransaction();
    for (String query : updateSql)
    {
     Log.d("update","Query: "+query);                    
     sqlDB.execSQL(query);
    }
    rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update("TICKET", values, selection, null);
    sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    Log.d("update","Aggiornate "+rowsUpdated+" righe");
    sqlDB.endTransaction();
` So now is all in one transaction?

Comment: Let me tell you both that this solution is really crap. You're scanning same table `1+ROWS*ROWS` times, without having guarantee that you're not performing same operation on same row more than once.

Comment: @dbw If you read documentation, it says "Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(...), update(..), et al, when possible." Regard "when possible".

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use SQL facilities to accomplish this task:

```
try {
    sqlDB.execSQL("UPDATE TICKET SET RIMANENTE = RIMANENTE - QUANTITA");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will, in a single statement - so, in a single transaction also - subtract `QUANTITA` to `RIMANENTE` in all rows from table `TICKET`.

EDIT:

```
UPDATE TICKET SET RIMANENTE = RIMANENTE - QUANTITA WHERE QUANTITA IS NOT NULL
```

is preferable, because if `QUANITTA` is not defined, i.e. NULL, `RIMANENTE` will be nulled.  `WHERE` clause prevents such from happen.